# Join para linq c#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, asp.net-core

Tenho a consulta a seguir em SQl Sevrer

```
SELECT PT.id, 
       P.nome AS Codigo, 
       PT.topologiaid, 
       TE.id  AS TipoEntidadeId 
FROM   [dbo].[propriedade] P 
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[propriedadetopologia] PT 
               ON P.id = PT.propriedadeid 
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[tipoentidade] TE 
               ON TE.nome = 'Propriedade' 
WHERE  P.tipopropriedadeid IS NOT NULL
```

Gostaria de fazer a mesma consulta no linq, mas não sei como fazer o ultimo Join, até agora tenho isso.

```
  var retorno = (from p in unitOfw.PropriedadeRepository.Get()
                                 join pt in unitOfw.PropriedadeTopologiaRepository.Get()
                                    on p.Id equals pt.PropriedadeId
                                 where p.TipoPropriedadeId != null
                                  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso resolve.

```
 var innerGroupJoinQuery2 =
             from p in unitOfw.PropriedadeRepository.Get()
             join pt in unitOfw.PropriedadeTopologiaRepository.Get()
             on p.Id equals pt.PropriedadeId
             from t in unitOfw.TipoEntidadeRepository.Get(y => y.Nome == "Propriedade")
             where p.TipoPropriedadeId != null
             select new { pt.Id, Codigo = p.Nome, Descricao = (string)null, pt.TopologiaId, TipoEntidadeId = t.Id };
```